# CQRS + EventSourcing. Change Aggregate Root history

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have following problem.
Given. CQRS + EventSourcing application. 
How is that possible to change the state of the Aggregate root in history?

For example, accounting application, accounter wants to apply transation but with past date. The event which will be stored in Event Store will have the older date than recent events, but the sequense number of this event will be bigger.

Repository will restore the state of aggregate root by ordering events by sequence number. And if we will take the snapshot for this past date - we will have aggregate root without this event.

We can surely change the logic of repository to order events by date, but we use external framework for CQRS, and this is not desirable.

Are there some elegant solutions for this case?

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is a bi-temporal implementation.

e.g. On dec 3rd we thought X == 12 (as-at), but on dec 5th we corrected the mistake and now know X == 14 on dec 3rd (as-of)

There are two ways to implement this

1) The event store holds as-at data and a projection holds as-of data (a possible variation is both an as-of and as-at projection as well)

2) The aggregate has an overloaded method indicating the desire for as-of vs as-at values from the event store. This will most likely involve using a custom secondary snapshot stream for as-of data values.

Your solution could very likely use both implementations as one is command focused and the other is query focused.

The as-of snapshots for the aggregate root in the second option would need to be rebuilt as corrective events are recieved.

Martin Folwler talks about this in this [article](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)

Note: The event store is still append only.

Answer (score 7):

In accounting you'll probably end up in jail if you change past bookings. Don't change the past. Use compensating commands instead.

Sorry, but you brought up the accounting example, which is probably a domain that's very strict about fiddling with past data without making the changes explicit.

If the above doesn't apply to your domain you can easily apply new events on top of older ones that change the state (and possibly the history) of your domain objects.

Take a booking to an account for example. The event might have occurred today, but it can set the actual booking date to some time in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You have stated that your business logic allows you to add a back-dated transaction; now I don't know why you'd want that, but there's nothing constraining your aggregate not to accept it. Of course the event will get a later event sequence number/version, but that's expected.

You don't need to fiddle with the infrastructure, repository or anything else to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Accounting doesn't let you change history. It only lets you add entries. It's up to your business logic to interpret the dates on these events as you will. In this case, the sequence of events is not just a persistence trick as with event sourcing, but the actual content of the domain!

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this is to think of the event as an explicit compensating action. For example, when your bank reverses a charge, they don't delete an existing transaction, they add a compensating transaction. This transaction may reference they transaction it wishes to compensate with respective dating. In this way, the events are a proper representation of reality.